# Data frame creation issue in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data={'a0':[[1,2,3]],'a1':[[5,6,2],[2,3]],'f1':[[2,5]]}
```

I need to create a data frame using this dict for which I ran the following commands.

```
for x in data:
    df[x]=pd.Series(data[x],index=None)
Output:
       a0         a1      f1
0  [1, 2, 3]  [5, 6, 2]  [2, 5]
```

Expected output:

```
     a0         a1      f1
0  [1, 2, 3]  [5, 6, 2]  [2, 5]
1             [2,3]
```

What am I missing in the code?

Thanks,
Sonia

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholders in your starter dictionary.

```
>>> data={'a0':[[1,2,3],[]],'a1':[[5,6,2],[2,3]],'f1':[[2,5],[]]}
>>> import pandas
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame()
>>> for x in data:
...     df[x]=pandas.Series(data[x],index=None)
...
>>> df
          a0         a1      f1
0  [1, 2, 3]  [5, 6, 2]  [2, 5]
1         []     [2, 3]      []
>>>
```

or you could use None as the placeholder...

```
>>> data={'a0':[[1,2,3],None],'a1':[[5,6,2],[2,3]],'f1':[[2,5],None]}
>>> for x in data:
...     df[x]=pandas.Series(data[x],index=None)
...
>>> df
          a0         a1      f1
0  [1, 2, 3]  [5, 6, 2]  [2, 5]
1       None     [2, 3]    None
>>>
```

If the first thing has more indexes then the second thing added to the df pandas defaults to `np.nan` so that might be the most sensible placeholder in this instance.

**EDIT:** you can index the DataFrame before adding any columns.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data={'a0':[[1,2,3]],'a1':[[5,6,2],[2,3]],'f1':[[2,5]]}
>>> a = pd.DataFrame().reindex([0,1])
>>> for x in data:
...     a[x]=pd.Series(data[x],index=None)
>>> a
          a0         a1      f1
0  [1, 2, 3]  [5, 6, 2]  [2, 5]
1        NaN     [2, 3]     NaN
```

Comment: Is there not a better way?

Comment: because the dict is created dynamically and its difficult to append to the values of the dict  during runtime

Answer (score 0):

```
data={'a0':[[1,2,3],''],'a1':[[5,6,2],[2,3]],'f1':[[2,5],'']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Comment: Try explain your answer so that those you are assisting can know what is happening. It also makes others reading your posts understand and award you points.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
```

### Trasnform "data" so all the value arrays are the same size

```
data={'a0':[[1,2,3]],'a1':[[5,6,2],[2,3]],'f1':[[2,5]]}
data
{'a0': [[1, 2, 3]], 'a1': [[5, 6, 2], [2, 3]], 'f1': [[2, 5]]}

rows=0
for k, v in data.items():
    if len(data[k]) >rows:
        rows = len(data[k])
    else:
        pass

for k,v in data.items():
    if rows > len(data[k]):
        for i in range(rows-len(data[k])):
            data[k].append([])
    else:
        pass

data
{'a0': [[1, 2, 3], []], 'a1': [[5, 6, 2], [2, 3]], 'f1': [[2, 5], []]}
```

### Once data is normalized, just assign the values to the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for k,v in data.items():
df[k] = v

df
    a0          a1          f1
0   [1, 2, 3]   [5, 6, 2]   [2, 5]
1   []          [2, 3]      []
```

### Replace the empty lists with nothing ( could also replace with np.nan, etc)

```
for column in df.columns:
    df[column]  = df[column].apply(lambda x: '' if len(x)==0 else x)

df
    a0          a1          f1
0   [1, 2, 3]   [5, 6, 2]   [2, 5]
1               [2, 3]
```